# Algebraic Issue

Tags: linear-algebra

I am a totally no good at mathematics, And that's why I don't know if the question already exist.

X1=1000
Y1=800
A1=700
B1=500

X2=1200
Y2=1000
A2=?
B2=?

PS:
X1/Y1=X2/Y2,
A1/B1=A2/B2

Actually I need the equation...not the answer because the values may change.

Please help me to find the equation for A2,B2

Thanks in advance

Comment: As currently written, $X_1$, $X_2$, $Y_1$, and $Y_2$ are irrelevant and there are an infinite number of solutions. Are you sure you haven't missed something out of the question?

Comment: Sorry Mr. Taylor, Actually the values are just made up. And I just got the answer now.

Its

X1/A1=X2/A2,
Y1/B1=Y2/B2

I am really sorry if I wasted you guys time